# Rails "No route matches POST /images/1" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, ruby-on-rails-5

I looked through several other similar help questions, and I'm not seeing my error. I have destroy, new, create all working, but post and show throw errors. Also oddly enough, clicking the 'edit' button on the index view throws an error, but going directly to http://localhost:3000/images/1 gives me the 'show' page (no idea why it isn't giving an edit page).

relevant files:

images_controller.rb

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @images = Image.all
  end

  def new
    @image = Image.new
  end

  def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)

    if @image.save
        redirect_to images_path, notice: "Your image #{@image.name} has been uploaded."
    else
        render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    @image.destroy
    redirect_to images_path, notice: "The image #{@image.name} has been removed from the database."
  end

  def show
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def image_params
    params.require(:image).permit(:name, :attachment)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do    
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
 resources :images#, only: [:index, :new, :create, :update, :edit, :show, :destroy]
 root "images#index" 
end
```

Note: I have also added the lines

```
get 'images/edit'

get 'images/details'
```

But to no avail.

index.html.erb:

```
<% if !flash[:notice].blank? %>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
  <%= flash[:notice] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<br />
<%= link_to "New Image", new_image_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<br />
<br />
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>View Link</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @images.each do |image| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= image.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "#{image.name}", image.attachment_url %></td>
        <td><%= button_to "Edit",  image, method: :edit, class: "btn btn-primary", confirm: "edit #{image.name}?" %></td>
        <td><%= button_to "Show",  image, method: :show, class: "btn btn-primary"%></td>
        <td><%= button_to "Delete",  image, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", confirm: "Are you sure that you wish to delete #{image.name}?" %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: A couple of strategies to solving this issue, if you haven't already tried them: 1) inspect the output of `rake routes` and compare to what is being rendered on the view in the browser. 2) rely on the url/path helpers the router provides (see pavan and gmrash's answers below and the documentation pavan links to for button_to) and 3) Try doing the simplest thing first--in your case, get rid of the css class and confirmation parts of the button_to call. Get it working then go back and add those in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose there are no HTTP methods like this:

```
method: :edit, method: :show
```

Try to do smth like this:

```
link_to "Edit", edit_image_path(image)
link_to "Show", image_path(image)
```

And remove this line from routes.rb

```
get 'images/edit'
```

resources has already created rout to edit action for you. You can see it http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes

Comment: also, if you want to call out the method explicitly (though I wouldn't worry about it) the method has to be one of the cannonical http methods: :get, :post, :patch, :put and :delete.  But the url/path helpers he suggests are the way to go.  You can also remove `get 'images/details'` as you've got to action in the controller you showed us.

Answer (score 2):

button_to by default will make post request you need `link_to "edit"` to make get request. when you type in your browser  http://localhost:3000/images/1 you are making get request so it works.

```
link_to "Edit", edit_image_path image
```

check these links for link_to and button_to 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to